# How to efficiently append data to an HDF5 table in C?

Tags: c, io, hdf5

I'm failing to save a large dataset of float values in an HDF5 file efficiently.

The data acquisition works as follows:
A fixed array of 'ray data' (coordintaes, directions, wavelength, intensity, etc.) is created and send to an external ray trace programm (its about 2500 values).
In return I get the same array but with changed data.
I now want to save the new coordinates in an HDF5 for further processing as a simple table.
These steps are repeated many times (about 80 000).

I followed the example of the HDF5group http://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/current/src/unpacked/examples/h5_extend_write.c, but unfortunatly the solution is quite slow.

Before I wrote the data directly into an hdf5 file I used a simple csv file, it takes about 80 sec for 100 repetitions, whereas it takes 160 sec appending to the hdf5 file.

The 'pseudo' code looks like this:

```
//n is a large number e.g. 80000 
for (i=0;i<n;++i):
{
    /*create an array of rays for tracing*/
    rays = createArray(i);
    /*trace the rays*/
    traceRays(&rays);
    /* write results to hdf5 file, m is a number around 2500 */
    for(j=0;j<m;j++):
    {
        buffer.x = rays[j].x
        buffer.y = rays[j].y
        //this seems to be slow: 
        H5TBappend_records(h5file,tablename, 1,dst_size, dst_offset, dst_sizes, &buffer)
        // this is fast:
        sprintf(szBuffer, "%15.6E,%14.6E\n",rays[j].x,rays[j].y)
        fputs(szBuffer, outputFile)
    }
}
```

I could imagine that it has something to do with the overhead of extending the table at each step ?
Any help would be appreciated.

cheers, 
Julian

Comment: I'm not familiar with HDF5's API, but does that `1` in the `H5TBappend_records` call tell it to allocate space for one more record? If so, you might be able to move that up to near `traceRays` and use `m` to allocate them in large(r) blocks.

Comment: Yes, it does. Moving it to the outer loop and allocate a larger block helps quite a bit ! Thx! Now it's about 120sec instead of 180, but it's still slower than writing it to a csv file.

Comment: Is there anything else you can move up and do in larger chunks? For example, a batch copy of the data, now that you've allocated a number of rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can get very good performance using the low level API of HDF5. I explain how to do it in [this detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15396949/208997).

Basically you need to either use a fixed-size dataset if you know its final size in advance (best case scenario), or use a chunked dataset which you can extend at will (a bit more code, more overhead, and choosing a good chunk size is critical for performance). In any case, then you can let the HDF5 library buffer the writes for you. It should be very fast.

In your case you probably want to create a compound datatype to hold each *record* of your *table*. Your dataset would then be a 1D array of your compound datatype.

NB: The methods used in the example code you linked to are correct. If it didn't work for you, that might be because your chunk size was too small.