# HDF5 writing a string header to a file

Tags: c++, string, hdf5

I am trying to write an HDF5 file from C++. The file basically contains a large timeseries matrix in the following format

```
TimeStamp    Property1      Property2
```

I have managed to write the data successfully, I created a dset and used the H5Dwrite function.

Now my question is how do I create a file header, in other words, if I want to write the following array to the file...

['TimeStamp', 'Property1', 'Property2']

...and tag it to the columns for ease of later use ( I am planning to analyze the matrix in Python). How to do that?

I tried to use H5Dwrite to write a string array but failed, I guess it wanted consistent datatypes, so it just wanted floats, which is the datatype for my data. Then I read about this metadata thing, but I am a bit lost as to how to use it? Any help would be much appreciated.

A related side question is can the first row of a matrix be a string and the others rows contain doubles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Clean solution(s)

If you store your data as a 1D array of a [compound datatype](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/UG/UG_frame11Datatypes.html) with members `TimeStamp`, `Property1`, `Property2`, etc. then the field names will be stored as metadata and it should be easy to read in Python.

I think there is another clean option but I will just mention it since I never used it myself: [HDF5's Table Interface](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/HL/RM_H5TB.html). Read the docs to see if you would prefer to use that.

### Direct answers to your question

Now the dirty options: you could add string attributes to your existing dataset. There are multiple ways to do that. You could have a single string attribute with all the field names separated by semicolons, or one attribute per column. I don't recommend it since that would be terribly non-standard.

> A related side question is can the first row of a matrix be a string and the others rows contain doubles?

No.

### Example using a compound datatype

Assuming you have a struct defined like this:

```
struct Point { double timestamp, property1, property2; };
```

and a vector of `Point`s:

```
std::vector<Point> points;
```

as well as a dataset `dset` and appropriate memory and file dataspaces, then you can create a compound datatype like this:

```
H5::CompType type(sizeof(DataPoint));
type.insertMember("TimeStamp", HOFFSET(Point, timestamp), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
type.insertMember("Property1", HOFFSET(Point, property1), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
type.insertMember("Property2", HOFFSET(Point, property2), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
```

and write data to file like this:

```
dset.write(&points[0], type, mem_space, file_space);
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, I was hoping you could join and shed some light, so this is appreciated. Having said that I am a real noob and also lost. I actually interestingly following this thread also answered by you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15379399/writing-appending-arrays-of-float-to-the-only-dataset-in-hdf5-file-in-c. This basically is what I am looking to do. Can you give me a one liner or two as to how to set the compound datatype? Basically in your examples terminology, the buffer is a buffer with names columns if that makes sense.

Comment: Basically I want to be able to write the data in chunks because the write process is connected to a real time call back process that writes the data as it occurs real time. I have used your previous solution in the link before and it works, just that now I want to name my data columns as I mention in this post. I will be really grateful if you could point me to modify your earlier post to include a facility to name the buffers.

Comment: I added an example. I used the C++ API since you mentioned C++ in your question but the idea is the same if you are using the C API. Apart from the datatype, nothing changes compared to [my answer to the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15396949/208997).

Comment: Thanks a lot Simon, I am still a bit stuck :) Do you want me to create a new post around your earlier answer? Basically I am not sure how to 1) resize the memory data_space and extend dataset 2) selecting hyperslab and appending 'points' to it 3) why do u use dset.write and not H5Dwrite. I can create a new post, and put in what I am trying and then you can edit it maybe. Hey, I appreciate a lot your help with this!

Comment: Basically you have to combine [extensible dataset](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15396949/208997) + [compound datatype](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23497148/208997). Yes it might be better if you create a new question with your best attempt and an explanation of where your are stuck (and tag it as C).

Comment: Thanks Simon, I actually in the interest of time will make do with just writing it as an attribute to the dset. I know this its a hack but it is easy and something that works right now :). So I declare the dset using H5Dcreate function, like this dset = H5Dcreate(file, "dset1", H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE, file_space, H5P_DEFAULT, plist, H5P_DEFAULT);. Can I just write say an attribute like, for example, "TimeStamp,Prop1,Prop2" to dset and if so how? I can just read the string in Python and later on split on "," to get the column names. So this solution works for me. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Can I for instance use the H5AWrite

Comment: Yep, you need the `H5A` family of functions. [Here is an example](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/Intro/IntroExamples.html#ReadWriteAttributes).