# hdf5 multiple extensible tables

Tags: c++, hdf5

I am analysing a huge number of files to strip out the important statistical informations. The analysis-program creates for every analysed file approx 3000 double-arrays of length n (approx. 100) together with a string which names the content of the respective array. I want to write the results into an hdf 5 file, where each array is written into a table whose name is the respective string. For that i use the following function :

```
#include "hdf5.h"
#include "hdf5_hl.h"
 hid_t       file_id;
 hsize_t     dims[RANK]={1,n};
 herr_t      status;
```

....

```
void hdf5_write ( double& array , string arrayname )
{     
 const char * tablename = arrayname.c_str();
 status = H5LTmake_dataset(file_id,tablename,RANK,dims,H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE,array);
}
```

This works fine for analysing the first file, however, when analysing multiple files one after another the existing tables are simply overwritten by the new arrays though I want that the new arrays are appended to the already existing tables respectively. Is there a hdf 5 function for that case?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't append using the high level (H5LT) interface.

Here is a [complete example using the low level interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15379399/writing-appending-arrays-of-float-to-the-only-dataset-in-hdf5-file-in-c). It is much more complex but it gives you total control.

Or if you think this is overkill, you can ask yourself if you really need a single large dataset vs multiple small ones. Depending on the application you have in mind, multiple datasets might simply be a better design.